# How to display image in listview from json dynamically

Tags: android, json, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I want to list text and image from json which is placed in particular url

I have successively displayed textview but how to display image my code is

```
public class AndroidJSONParsingActivity extends ListActivity {


    // url to make request
    private static String url = "***MY URL***";

    // JSON Node names

    private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_PRICE = "price";
    private static final String TAG_URL = "hosting_thumbnail_url";


    // contacts JSONArray


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_android_jsonparsing);

        // Hashmap for ListView
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Creating JSON Parser instance
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONArray json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

        try {
            // Getting Array of Contacts


            // looping through All Contacts
            for(int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++){
                JSONObject c = json.getJSONObject(i);

                // Storing each json item in variable
                String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                String email = c.getString(TAG_PRICE);
                //String  image1 = c.getString( TAG_URL);

                // creating new HashMap
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                map.put(TAG_PRICE, email);
                //map.put(TAG_URL, image1);


                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                contactList.add(map);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        /**
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * */
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, contactList,
                R.layout.list_item,
                new String[] { TAG_NAME, TAG_PRICE }, new int[] {
                        R.id.name, R.id.email });

        setListAdapter(adapter);


    }

}
```

i want listview like this "http://pic002.cnblogs.com/images/2012/372551/2012021011374176.jpg"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to write a custom list adapter. Google for "android custom listadapter image". The first hit is [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/) one, which looks like a decent example.

Answer (score 0):

As SimonSays said, you have to implement your own `ListView` adapter class and its `getView()` method.

If you plan to obtain these JSON objects dynamically in ListView I strongly recommend to use some `Thread` mechanism, that would set data from that JSON object to `ListView` immediately when it's obtained - i.e. `AsyncTask`